# Error running Cassandra client on Quarkus

Tags: quarkus

I was trying to run the Quarkus example on a Cassandra client given in the link below

https://quarkus.io/guides/cassandra

and it seems not working.

Does anyone have a clue what's going on?

Quarkus 2.7.x
Java11

```
ERROR [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
        [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type demo.FruitDao and qualifiers [@Default]
        - java member: demo.FruitService#dao
        - declared on CLASS bean [types=[demo.FruitService, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=demo.FruitService]
        at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.processErrors(BeanDeployment.java:1202)
        at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:272)
        at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanProcessor.initialize(BeanProcessor.java:134)
        at io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor.validate(ArcProcessor.java:462)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:882)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type demo.FruitDao and qualifiers [@Default]
        - java member: demo.FruitService#dao
        - declared on CLASS bean [types=[demo.FruitService, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=demo.FruitService]
        at io.quarkus.arc.processor.Beans.resolveInjectionPoint(Beans.java:428)
        at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanInfo.init(BeanInfo.java:508)
        at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:260)
        ... 13 more

        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:330)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:252)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:60)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.firstStart(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:92)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:455)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:66)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInCl(CuratedApplication.java:150)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInAugmentClassLoader(CuratedApplication.java:106)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:132)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:62)
Caused by: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
        [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type demo.FruitDao and qualifiers [@Default]
```

Comment: https://github.com/pranavnayak/quarkus-project9-cassandra-client works in my local. same project ?

Comment: Thank for your reply. It didn't for me. Java11 and Quarkus 2.7.1. I am not sure about the pom.xml file. Did you use the same in the example?

Comment: did you try to compile https://github.com/pranavnayak/quarkus-project9-cassandra-client ? I am using mvn 3.8.6 and openjdk 19 in win11

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, I looked at the quickstart like you but my mistake was that I used the datastax driver mapper processor and not the quarkus one.

Check if you have this annotation processor in your maven compiler plugin.

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>com.datastax.oss.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>cassandra-quarkus-mapper-processor</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.2</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Awesome. This made the trick. I do really appreciate your clue.
I was using the Datastax processor instead of the Quarkus one. Cheers.